# Moment.js, Change UTC date to given UTC offset

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm receiving from the back-end 2 values.

1. UTC date `2019-05-01T17:38:00Z`.
2. UTC offset value `UTC+10`, `UTC-2`.

I need to add or subtract from the date based on the offset value.

Answer (score 1):

Use moment().utcOffset()

```
// these are equivalent
moment().utcOffset("+08:00");
moment().utcOffset(8);
moment().utcOffset(480);
```

Comment: I have date: `2019-06-16T08:33:00Z`  
`moment(date).format() = "2019-06-16T11:33:00+03:00"`  
And also `moment(date).utcOffset(+2).format() = 2019-06-16T11:33:00+03:00`.  
It's the same date and hours